# Where can I find more information on secure polygon problems and questions related to it?

Tags: dynamical-systems, geometric-topology

Recently I watched got interested in secure polygon problem (SPP), but not only that, I would also want to learn more about this type of mathematical structures in general.
 As I understand, the SPP is closely related to studies of dynamical systems and topology.
**What books/information sources would you recommend to start my journey with such mathematical ideas and also what math branches should I learn more about to explore things similar to SPP?**

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on the topic but I can only guess that you're asking due to the "[PBS Infinite Series video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7gp9c2p0UQ)" on that topic.  If you haven't already, check out this blog post from the host:

- **https://www.math3ma.com/blog/is-the-square-a-secure-polygon** - this blog post explains in detail how to solve the "Secure Polygon problem" for squares. This article also calls this a type of *billiard problem*.
- Just as important, this article links to [a 2014 lecture by Maryam Mirzakhani](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tprlQMClSYQ) on Dynamics and Moduli Spaces of curves.  This lecture I believe provides some background information on the concepts behind this problem. The "secure square" problem is introduced @25:50 per the first video.
- The first video also makes mention of [this Numberphile video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xhj5er1k6GQ) on the related [Illumination problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illumination_problem).  At least this topic is covered in Wikipedia.  I'm guessing that this can also be considered a type of *billiard problem*.
- In terms of general, broad topics: [Dynamical systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_system) and [Topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topology) are entire fields of study in and of themselves that would likely provide the requisite background to study this problem in-depth, especially the general non-square polynomial version of the problem.  This is not an area I have studied so I'd leave it to others to post any introductory material.

Overall, I doubt that this specific problem has many dedicated resources besides those I've listed. The rest may involve self-study and may be a sparsely-researched problem.  That's not to say that individual papers couldn't have been published on the topic.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've attempted to clarify what the resources I've listed discuss.  Originally I was going to comment on the question but I figured an answer might be more helpful.  Thus, my knowledge of the topic is limited, although my own searching seems to indicate that this problem very little in terms of published material. 

As a side note:  how does the bot figure out the quality of the answer?  Or does this bot assist a human in marking an answer?